# Unexpected Result Structure C

Tags: c, struct

I am beginner in C and i am having trouble in structure in c, I have created an array of structure p[2] and then have taken the input and just printed it but the results are unexpected, struct was defined as

```
struct person{
int eno;
float height;
char name[10];
}p[2];
```

and main function as

```
int main(void)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
   scanf("%d%f",&p[i].eno,&p[i].height);
   fgets(p[i].name,10,stdin);
  } 
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",p[i].eno);
    printf("%f\n",p[i].height);
    puts(p[i].name);
  }
  return 0;
}


Input :
10
11.0
abcdef
11
12.3
xyzpa

Output:
10
11.000000


0
0.000000
abcdef
```

Here is the Ideone link: http://ideone.com/8gIQU3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `fgets()` is getting the end-of-line left over in the input buffer from scanning the numbers. Add whitspace to the end of your numbers format string.

Also, you should always check that `scanf()` has succeeded before relying on it. I/O is brittle and can fail, especially when the other end is a human.